# Set the range of the y axis in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I made a line plot with Plotly. How can I set the range of Y axis to always have it in [0; 10]?

```
layout = go.Layout(
    title=go.layout.Title(text="Test", xref="paper", x=0),
    xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(
        tickmode="linear",
        tickfont=dict(size=10),
        title=go.layout.xaxis.Title(font=dict(size=14, color="#7f7f7f")),
    ),
    yaxis=go.layout.YAxis(
        title=go.layout.yaxis.Title(text=y, font=dict(size=14, color="#7f7f7f")),
    ),
)

data = [go.Scatter(x=x1, y=y1)]
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

#### Update for newer versions

When setting up a figure you can use plotly's [magic underscore notation](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#magic-underscore-notation) and specify `layout_yaxis_range=[<from_value>, <to_value>]` like this:

```
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[-4,4])
```

Or if you've already got a figure named `fig`, you can use:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[-4,4])
```

And:

```
fig.update(layout_yaxis_range = [-4,4])
```

Or:

```
fig.update_yaxes(range = [-4,4])
```

#### Figure:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(4)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))

# plotly line chart
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='lines'), layout_yaxis_range=[-4,4])
               
fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[-4,4])
fig.show()
```

---

#### Original answer using `plotly.offline`,  `iplot` and no magic underscore notation:

When setting up a figure, use:

```
layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(range=[fromValue, toValue])
```

Or if you've already got a figure named `fig`, you can use:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(range=[fromValue,toValue]))
```

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code for Jupyter Notebook:**

```
# imports
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# data
np.random.seed(4)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))

# line
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
)

# layout
layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(range=[-4,4])
)

# Plot
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

**Some important details:**

With this setup, you can easily add an y axis title like this:

```
# layout
layout = go.Layout(yaxis=dict(range=[-4,4]), title='y Axis')
)
```

It's a *little* more tricky if you'd like to format that title further. I find it easiest to actually add another element with `title = go.layout.yaxis.Title(text='y Axis', font=dict(size=14, color='#7f7f7f')`. As long as you do it the right way, you should not experience the situation in your comment above:

> Thanks. I tried it. But then I have 2 definitions of yaxis in the
> Layout: yaxis=dict(range=[0, 10]) and yaxis=go.layout.YAxis. Therefore
> an error appears.

Take a look at this:

**Plot:**

[image]

**Complete code with y-axis text formatting:**

```
# imports
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# data
np.random.seed(4)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
y = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(50))

# line
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=x,
    y=y,
)

# layout
layout = go.Layout(
    yaxis=dict(range=[-4,4],
    title = go.layout.yaxis.Title(text='y Axis', font=dict(size=14, color='#7f7f7f')))
)

# Plot
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace], layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Comment: The update_layout call can be simplified with plotly.py's magic underscore notation: `fig.update_layout(yaxis_range=[fromValue, toValue])`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you right you want to limit the range of the y-axis itself. You can pass a dict in the keyword argument `yaxis`. It could be something like `go.Layout(yaxis=dict(range=[0, 10]))` I hope this helps you.

Comment: For more documentation on this topic see: https://plot.ly/python/axes/#setting-the-range-of-axes-manually