# How to reduce the space between two graphs?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Here I want to reduce the space between two graphs, but I couldn't.
Here is the code

```
import dash                     # pip install dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px     # pip install plotly==5.2.2
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd             # pip install pandas

df_fddevents = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Event="On", EventStartTime='2022-01-01 08:00:00', EventEndTime='2022-01-01 16:45:00', Point="Switch1", width=0.5),
    dict(Event="Off", EventStartTime='2022-01-01 16:45:00', EventEndTime='2022-01-02 08:00:00', Point="Switch1", width=0.3),
    dict(Event="On", EventStartTime='2022-01-02 08:00:00', EventEndTime='2022-01-02 16:45:00', Point="Switch1", width=0.5),
    dict(Event="On", EventStartTime='2022-01-01 08:00:00', EventEndTime='2022-01-01 10:00:00', Point="Switch2", width=0.3),
    dict(Event="Off", EventStartTime='2022-01-01 10:00:00', EventEndTime='2022-01-01 13:45:00', Point="Switch2", width=0.5),
    dict(Event="On", EventStartTime='2022-01-02 08:00:00', EventEndTime='2022-01-02 16:00:00', Point="Switch2", width=0.3)])

print(df_fddevents)
fig_gantt = px.timeline(df_fddevents, x_start="EventStartTime", x_end="EventEndTime", y="Event", color="Point", height=250)
fig_gantt.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed")
fig_gantt.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
for i, d in enumerate(fig_gantt.data):
    d.width = df_fddevents[df_fddevents['Point']==d.name]['width']
fig_gantt.show()
#Line Chart for all analog points
df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:00:00', Value=90, Point="A", Unit='%', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:15:00', Value=80, Point="A", Unit='%', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:30:00', Value=85, Point="A", Unit='%', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:45:00', Value=92, Point="A", Unit='%', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:00:00', Value=100, Point="A", Unit='%', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:15:00', Value=72, Point="A", Unit='%', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:00:00', Value=22, Point="B", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:15:00', Value=22, Point="B", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:30:00', Value=23, Point="B", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:45:00', Value=20, Point="B", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:00:00', Value=21, Point="B", Unit='°C', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:15:00', Value=23, Point="B", Unit='°C', DataType='Fault'),    
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:00:00', Value=24, Point="C", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:15:00', Value=24, Point="C", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:30:00', Value=24, Point="C", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:45:00', Value=24, Point="C", Unit='°C', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:00:00', Value=24, Point="C", Unit='°C', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:15:00', Value=24, Point="C", Unit='°C', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:00:00', Value=60, Point="D", Unit='Pa', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:15:00', Value=58, Point="D", Unit='Pa', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:30:00', Value=62, Point="D", Unit='Pa', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:45:00', Value=61, Point="D", Unit='Pa', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:00:00', Value=64, Point="D", Unit='Pa', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:15:00', Value=59, Point="D", Unit='Pa', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:00:00', Value=0, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:15:00', Value=0, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:30:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 00:45:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:00:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:15:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Fault'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:30:00', Value=0, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 01:45:00', Value=0, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 02:00:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 02:15:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 02:30:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
    dict(DateTime='2022-01-01 02:45:00', Value=1, Point="E", Unit='Binary', DataType='Normal'),
])

figline = px.line(df2, x="DateTime", y="Value", color="Point", line_group="Unit", hover_name="Point", facet_row="Unit",
        line_shape="spline", render_mode="svg")
#figline.update_xaxes(zeroline=True, zerolinewidth=2, zerolinecolor='LightPink')
#figline.update_xaxes(ticks= "inside",tickson ="boundaries", tickcolor= "#16537e", ticklen=70,)
#figline.update_yaxes(ticks="inside",tickcolor= "#16537e", tickson ="boundaries", ticklen=950)
figline.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=10, gridcolor='red')
figline.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='red')
figline.update_yaxes(autorange=True)
figline.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
figline.show()
```

[Here this is the problem where two graphs are plotted in plotly but the space between them is too far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZQuL.png)

[it is the expected solution where two graphs are situated not so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDVC4.png) [it is the another expected solution where two graphs are situated in single axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP8Hb.png)

Comment: To close the gap between two graphs without using subplots, change the margin settings. `fig_gantt.update_layout(margin={'t':20,'b':0,'l':0,'r':0})`, `figline.update_layout(margin={'t':0,'b':0,'l':0,'r':0})`

Comment: How can marge the x axis of both the chart? I want to use the x axis of the second chart which is line chart for both the chart

Comment: See this:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704058/plotly-how-to-set-the-range-of-the-y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704058/plotly-how-to-set-the-range-of-the-y-axis)